# Reading comma separated string values as dictionary elements in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string as below

`'type': 'singlechoice',        'add_to_user_messages': false,        'text': 'See you tomorrow',        'next': '31'`

All the elements can be treated as key value pairs. I want to construct a python dictionary from this string.
Is there a straight forward method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings looks exactly like you have posted, you can replace single quotes with double quotes, enclose it in curly braces and load with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "'type': 'singlechoice',        'add_to_user_messages': false,        'text': 'See you tomorrow',        'next': '31'"
>>> modified_s = '{' + s.replace("'", '"') + '}'                                                            
>>> json.loads(modified_s)
{u'text': u'See you tomorrow', u'type': u'singlechoice', u'add_to_user_messages': False, u'next': u'31'}
```

Though, I'm not sure where your input string is coming from and cannot guarantee the solution would cover all the variety of input strings you might have.

Or, another "dirty" solution would be to replace `false` with `False`, `true` with `True`, enclose with curly braces and load via [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> modified_s = s.replace("false", "False").replace("true", "True")
>>> modified_s = '{' + s.replace("false", "False").replace("true", "True") + '}'
>>> literal_eval(modified_s)
{'text': 'See you tomorrow', 'type': 'singlechoice', 'add_to_user_messages': False, 'next': '31'}
```

Comment: Thanks @alexce , I thought of that but the problem is that the string is generated dynamically. Although the format is same always, I cannot simply replace the single quotes as in some instances, values in the key-value pairs might also contain single quotes. How can I get around with that problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: @abhinavDAIICT yeah, we can improve the first option to safely handle the quotes. Could u first check if the second option works for you? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alexe, the second option works almost  and generates the dictionary but there's a small issue - It is mandatory to replace `true` with `True` and the dictionary is created but on validating the JSON it shows an error. Actually, `True` is not valid in JSON, `true` is allowed. You can verify this at [http://jsoneditoronline.org] with this generated dictionary -

`{'text': 'Thanks Shreya :)', 'type': 'singlechoice', 'add_to_user_messages': True, 'next': '4'}`

Comment: @abhinavDAIICT yeah, `true` is a valid JSON value, I understand. But, since we use `literal_eval`, we cannot afford having literal `true` or `false` as a dictionary value - that's why the replacement is needed. It's not clean though - the `true` and `false` would also be replaced elsewhere - for instance, inside the dictionary keys. Probably a more strict replacement needed, smth like `.replace(": true", ": True")` or a regular expression substitution applying more strict rules where `true` or `false` can be found and should be replaced..

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

The main issue is false being converted to string

```
a = "'type': 'singlechoice',        'add_to_user_messages': false,        'text': 'See you tomorrow',        'next': '31'"

b = map(lambda x: x.split(":"), a.split(","))
c = map(lambda x: (x[0].replace("\'", "").strip(), x[1].replace("\'", "").strip() ) , b)
d = dict(c)


print(d)


#{'next': '31', 'type': 'singlechoice', 'text': 'See you tomorrow', 'add_to_user_messages': 'false'}
```